# Can I drop a variable from a logistic regression, score on the other variables and then add back in for a different model? (See Body)

Tags: regression, logistic

So what I have is a logistic regression equation with the first variable having a large (not overly so) coefficient ie.

ln(p/1-p) = C + B1*V1 + B2*V2 + B3*V3 + B4*V4 +B5*V5

Because this coefficient is so large there is a need to remove this as part of a strategy but we could also try to adjust the power of this variable in the above model. I’ve considered ridge regression but I think the following method is much simpler and quicker if it indeed works.

My question is can I have the following model with B1*V1 removed:

ln(p/1-p) = C + B2*V2 + B3*V3 + B4*V4 +B5*V5

Then convert to a score base on pdo and base score and use this score to go into a new model with the previous first variable ie.

ln(p/1-p) = C + B1.1*(Score calculated from first model) + B1*V1

And would this result in the same model? I am thinking it would not because the iterative process would have less coefficients to optimise and the score from the previous model would be much more predictive than the variable we dropped and used in the second model.

Comment: Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, having a variable with a very large $\beta$ in the logistic model, even with $\beta=\infty$, does not cause a problem.  It still leads to the right probability estimate.  Of course we don't really believe the probability to be 1.0, and penalized maximum likelihood estimation will lead to a more reasonable probability.  But if you flip a coin 10 times and get 10 heads the maximum likelihood estimate of P(heads) is 1.0, leading to a log odds of $\infty$.

Large $\beta$ is not a reason to remove a variable from the model.  Only worry about this if you get probability estimates that don't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why splitting to two linear models will work better. Also, large coefficients are not necessarily a problem. If you are worried about the large coefficient, you can try one of the following (depending on the specific details of your problem)

- standartization or normalization - it can improves stability, and can make coefficients smaller.
- regularization - it can improve generalization and performance on out of sample data and almost by definition will make coefficients smaller.